# Make input character case not sensitive

Tags: bash

I want to use this script to to access capital letters and small letters.

```
### User prompts
read -p "Would you like us to perform the option: \"(Y|N)\" " inPut

case $inPut in
# echoing a command encapsulated by
# backticks (``) executes the command
"Y") echo 'Starting.....'
donwload_source_code
;;

# depending on the scenario, execute the other option
# or leave as default
"N") echo 'Stopping execution'
exit
;;

esac
```

For example Y and y to lead to one switch case. Is there any solution?

Comment: What I normally do is, immediately after receiving the input, I convert it to upper case and from that point on always compare to uppercase values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the construct in `case` to `y|Y` to work with all versions of `bash`

```
### User prompts
read -p "Would you like us to perform the option: \"(Y|N)\" " inPut

case $inPut in
# echoing a command encapsulated by
# backticks (``) executes the command
y|Y) echo 'Starting.....'
donwload_source_code
;;

# depending on the scenario, execute the other option
# or leave as default
n|N) echo 'Stopping execution'
exit
;;

esac
```

Comment: By the way can I use `"y"|"Y")`?

Answer (score 3):

Change one line in existing code: More info [Here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) .  Note that bash Version 4+ is needed for this. As an alternate : `echo $var |awk '{print toupper($0)}'` can be used.

```
case ${inPut^} in
```

Example:

```
sh-4.1$ var=y
sh-4.1$ echo $var
y                           #Lower case
sh-4.1$ echo ${var^}        #Modified to upper case
Y
sh-4.1$
```

Modified script:

```
### User prompts
read -p "Would you like us to perform the option: \"(Y|N)\" " inPut

case ${inPut^} in
# echoing a command encapsulated by
# backticks (``) executes the command
"Y") echo 'Starting.....'
donwload_source_code
;;

# depending on the scenario, execute the other option
# or leave as default
"N") echo 'Stopping execution'
exit
;;

esac
```

Comment: Note that it requires bash 4+.

Comment: I have GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16). And I get `run.sh: line 551: ${inPut^}: bad substitution`

Comment: `input=$(echo $input |awk '{print toupper($0)}')`  try this

Comment: also, The other answer mentioned by Inian is better approach, you should go with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `nocasematch` option to perform case-insensitive matches.

```
$ foo=Y
$ case $foo in y) echo "matched y" ;; *) echo "no match" ;; esac
no match
$ shopt -s nocasematch
$ case $foo in y) echo "matched y" ;; *) echo "no match" ;; esac
matched y
```